# Is a typedef a definition?

Tags: c++

I'm really confused. I am reading TC++PL by Bjarne Stroustrup (special edition, 19th print - Sep 2010). Let me quote a part of the book, highlighting my confusion:

```
char ch;
string s;
int count = 1;
const double pi = 3.1415926535897932385;
extern int error_number;

const char* name = "Njal";
const char* season[] = { "spring", "summer", "fall", "winter" };

struct Date { int d, m, y; };
int day(Date* p) { return p->d; }
double sqrt(double);
template<class T> T abs(T a) { return a<0 ? -a : a; }

typedef complex<short> Point;
struct User;
enum Beer { Carlsberg, Tuborg, Thor };
namespace NS { int a; }
```

> As can be seen from these examples, a declaration can do more than simply
>   associate a type with a name. Most of these declarations are also definitions;
>   that is, they also define an entity for the name to which they refer. For ch,
>   that entity is the appropriate amount of memory to be used as a variable – that
>   memory will be allocated. For day it is the specified function. For the
>   constant pi, it is the value 3.1415926535897932385. For Date, that entity is
>   a new type. **For Point it is the type complex so that Point becomes a
>   synonym for complex**. Of the declarations above, only these are not also
>   definitions:

```
double sqrt(double);
extern int error_number;
struct User;
typedef complex<short> Point <-- WTF;
```

Isn't the sentence in bold conflicting with the list given below it? Is a typedef just a declaration or also a definition? Is this an error in the book?

Comment: `bjarne-stroustrup` is a tag now?

Comment: Looks like it has been a tag for a while.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I'm totally confused by this. The standard is clear. Typedef is just a declaration. Not definition.

> **3.1-2**
>
> A declaration is a definition unless
>   it declares a function without
>   specifying the function’s body (8.4),
>   it contains the extern specifier
>   (7.1.1) or a linkage-specification24)
>   (7.5) and neither an initializer nor a
>   function-body, it declares a static
>   data member in a class declaration
>   (9.4), it is a class name declaration
>   (9.1), or it is a **typedef
>   declaration (7.1.3)**, a
>   using-declaration (7.3.3), or a
>   using-directive (7.3.4).

Edit: Oh, I just realized why. You can typedef a declaration, therefore a typedef has to be a declaration itself.

Comment: indeed typedef just introduces a synonym, and you do not need to instantiate a synonym.

Answer (score 2):

A typedef is a type alias, not a new type unto itself. With a typedef, nothing new is defined, but rather an existing definition is given a second name -- just like nightcracker is your alias, not your real name, but they both refer to the same entity: you.

Comment: There is no such thing as a type alias.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be - how you'd call it, then (except "type typedef" or sth like this) ?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: What do you mean?  An alias is another name for something.  And that's exactly what a typedef is, another name for a type.

Comment: @Kiril The best would be to call it the same way the standard does. "7.1.3-1 A typedef-name is thus a synonym for another type."

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: It is a common complaint that typdef is badly named (as it creates an alias not a new type). Try `typedef int Wight; typedef int Height; Height height = 72; Wight weight = 230; height= weight;` Here there is no complaints about assigning a weight onto a height variable, this is because everything is just an integer. If you look at the D language they explicitly complain about it and re-name it to typealias.

Comment: @Martin: behold `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` :)

Comment: @mlimber: This is true, but irrelevant. typedefs aren't non-definitions just because they create synonyms. References are synonyms, but `int &i = j;` is still a definition. typedefs are declarations because that's how the standard chooses to categorise them.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: References are object aliases, while typedef are type aliases. mlimber was very specific about it being a type alias.

Comment: @Matthieu M: I am aware. But its ugly.

Comment: @Martin: yes :/ What's funny is that what we want here is something akin to inheritance, but without the virtual / data extension tidbits. *too* simple perhaps to warrant implementation :(

Comment: @Matthieu M: What I want is that ALL types be class like. So I can do `class Height: public int {};`

Comment: @Martin: of course. Nevertheless, what mlimber says merely states that typedef creates a type alias. It doesn't address the question (whether typedefs are definitions or not, whether the book contains a contradiction or not). If mlimber intended an unspoken assertion that "the fact that it creates type aliases implies that nothing is defined *and hence it is not a definition*", then that is spurious reasoning. It just begs the question, by assuming without proof that the fact the thing created is a (type) alias, has something to do with whether it's a definition or just a declaration.

Answer (score 1):

How do you tell a difference between a declaration that is a definition and a declaration that is not?

Easy: *you can only have one definition* of each entity, but as many declarations as you want.

Because you can say

```
 typedef int Foo;
 typedef int Foo;
```

without any problem, this is not a definition. Or perhaps because this is not a definition, you can say that. Either way, your compiler can easily tell which is which.

Note that in C it is illegal to repeat a typedef, so a typedef declaration *is* a definition in C.

Answer (score 0):

A definition creates an object, so:

```
int x;
```

is a definition of an int called x. A typedef does not create an object, it creates a new name for an existing type, so it is not  a definition.

Comment: `struct Date { int d, m, y; };` doesn't create an object either - it's still a (type) definition.

Comment: What makes you think that definition must create an object? Definition of inline function may create nothing still being a definition. Definition of a class may also create nothing. Only definition of an object creates an object.